# Form submitting python

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to automate some stuff i have to do periodicaly on a site.
First of all I have to login and I am trying with Mechanize:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.open("http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/")

#Seleziona il form di login di nome Form1
formcount=0
for frm in br.forms():  
  if str(frm.attrs["id"])=="Form1":
    break
  formcount=formcount+1
br.select_form(nr=formcount)

#imposta username e password
#br['username']='asdasd'
br.set_value('******',id="username")
br.set_value('******',id="password")

#submit
res = br.submit()
print res.read()
```

I commented out the line `#br['username']='asdasd'` cause it raises an `ControlNotFoundError`; so I opted for the `.set_value` method (I'm not sure if it is working, but it does not raise any exception).
The problem is that after the `br.submit()` the page stays the same. 
How do I get the updated page?

EDIT 1:

I don't know if this the way I was meant to do it; if it was so, then nothing changed.

```
import cookielib
import mechanize 

br = mechanize.Browser()
#br.set_handle_robots(False)
#br.set_handle_redirect(True)


# Enable cookie support for urllib2
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
# Broser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
# Set refresh handle
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize.HTTPRefererProcessor(), max_time=1)
headers = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'),('Connection', 'keep-alive')] 

br.open("http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/")

#Seleziona il form di login di nome Form1
br.select_form(nr=1)

#imposta username e password
br.set_value('****',id="username")
br.set_value('****',id="password")

br.select_form(nr=0)

#submit
res = br.submit()
print res.read()
```

Comment: At some point if you use mechanize enough you're going to give up on it and switch to requests. This looks like a good time.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize has an option to redirect page after submit form.
You can try with the following code before submit form:

```
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
I noticed that the form where the input fields are is within another form where method and action are defined.
I tried to select the parent form but it doesn't find the controls, I tried to fill the children form and then select the parent and submit but I'm still getting the same page.

Comment: OK, let me check the site first.

Comment: Can you please try with the following url? http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/#login-modal

Comment: On the .open():
BrowserStateError: can't fetch relative reference: not viewing any document

Comment: Actually I cannot understand the language of the page. but you can also try: # Enable cookie support for urllib2
            cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
            br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

            # Broser options
            br.set_handle_equiv(True)
            br.set_handle_redirect(True)
            br.set_handle_referer(True)
            br.set_handle_robots(False)

            # Set refresh handle
            br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize.HTTPRefererProcessor(), max_time=1) and .braddheaders = headers

Comment: headers = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'),('Connection', 'keep-alive')]